# Should I use Box2D for collision-detection only (not simulating physics)?

Tags: collision-detection, box2d, physics

I'm using Box2D only to check collisions and for *no physical simulation*. I create bodies (and shapes for them) and use my own code to move them, by setting their velocities and positions every frame. I only fetch collision data from the Box2D world.

Is this a good idea? For example, can it cause undefined behaviour from Box2D? Is there a more performance friendly way of dealing with different shape collision detections?

Do better methods exist for this?

Comment: I don't understand.  What would you use Box2D for if not physics?  What do you mean by "precise shape description"?

Comment: @Anko I create shapes for my game objects. Move them and get collisions from Box2D. This is what I mean.

Comment: Ah, I get it now! I made some edits to clarify.

Comment: Don't you have to call `b2World.Step` (which simulates physics) to get your contact listener to fire? (I'm also curious why you're not using Box2D's physics.)

Comment: Initial search on the internet suggests it is possible http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/box2d-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone but other people suggest the collision detection routines won't be stable if you don't use box2d's collision response, which is part of the physics engine. I can understand why - box2d tries very hard to keep objects from penetrating. Once they do the collision engine has a much harder job doing the right thing and could become unstable.

Comment: My question was edited wrongly. I don't ask if I can or cannot do that. I have done that, and it works. I ask if I should do that or I should do something else if I need only collision detection mechanism with precise polygon and circle shapes.

Comment: That seems too broad or opininated, to me (I mis-clicked the close reason but don't really see a need to reopen-reclose to fix it).

Comment: I don't see why this is a off-topic question, it seems pretty valid to me. But it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309280/box2d-for-collision-detection-only, by the way: don't do it, it is going to look choppy and unstable, since the integrator is part of the collision detection on Box2D, that is, it uses the velocity, torque and acceleration data as part of the guess-work to detect collisions.

Comment: @GustavoMaciel I don't understand why it should be choppy. And what is the better alternative to do collision detection?

Comment: If you just get collision data and teleport your bodies around with setPosition, Box2D will miss the velocity, acceleration, force, torque and angular speed data, since you're placing the bodies by hand, and not letting Box2D do it's simulation job. For this, Box2D will not be capable of telling your collision with precision, but maybe some frames late, or even with wrong data, since the data missing plays a big part on the collision predicting it uses for dynamic bodies.

Your alternative is to use the full simulation on Box2D, or not use it at all. That is, if you want a good game.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually the answer to my question. I would accept that!